# Write value into characteristics is not persistent

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

Using CoreBlueTooth I write some hex value into a writable characteristics of the peripheral. `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error` gets called with no error. Also I am able to see the newly written value in the characteristics while debugging with breakpoint. But as soon as the connection is cancelled or I stop running the app, the characteristics value is reverted to the default value. Is there anything else I need to do to retain the value in the characteristics ?.

Comment: It's back on the device? After `didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` you called a `readValueForCharacteristic:`? Then the device has the correct value? Is What is the other device? It may be a bug on the other device?

Comment: It may be an issue with the device.  A call back to didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error without an error indicates it was written successfully over Bluetooth.  That does not mean that the device won't revert to a previous value based on it's internal rules.  Some devices, for example, may require you write to another characteristic to commit changes.

Comment: I called readValueForCharacteristic: in didWriteValueForCharacteristic. Then didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: got called where I added break point and could see the newly added value.

Comment: I think maybe after didWriteValueForCharacteristic, it's only write some data on it's memory, and which will be reset when you connect again or start the app and give some reset after connection?